# How to render org-mode file from jekyll/github without converting .org to .html?

Tags: github, jekyll, org-mode

Is it possible to render org file directly from jekyll? Thanks.
I found some guide just told me that first create org file, then convert it to html, and at last publish in jekyll.
Can I ommit "convert" step?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to export/convert the org file to HTML?

Comment: I want to keep one copy of the source file i.e. .org file

Answer (score 0):

I believe by `convert` they meant `export`.  The original file will not be lost on export, a new one will be created with the content converted to the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need checkout [those](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/), and for your site you can use [org-js](https://github.com/mooz/org-js)